# Why do relative imports from a '..' parent index file cause asynchronous module resolution behaviour?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, dependencies

I have a repo with a structure like this:

```
src/ 
   index.ts
   main.ts
   bar/
      file.ts
      index.ts
   foo/
      fooFile.ts
```

the `src/index` is intended as just a top level index file that exports everything in my package.

However, the behaviour I'm tracking down actually requires that I call some functionality within this file, I'll get into that in a bit.

`src/bar/file.ts` exports a plain string.

`src/foo/fooFile.ts` imports that string from the parent `..` index.

```
// comments relate to what happens if you run `node lib/index.js`
import { fileName } from "..";
import {fileName as fileName2} from "../bar"; 

export const test = "test"; 

const myData = {
    data: fileName,  // This resolves to undefined, 
    data2: fileName2 //This resolves to "bar"
}; 


export function main() {
    console.log(myData); 
    console.log(fileName);  // This resolves to "bar"
}
```

If my `src/index.ts` looks like:

```
import {main} from "./foo/fooFile";
export * from "./bar"; 
export * from "./foo/fooFile"; 

main();
```

Then we get this asynchronous kind of behaviour - where the import of `fileName` from `..` resolves as undefined when declaring the `myData` const, but resolves the string at runtime.

Whereas if I import from `../bar` then I get the string in both instances.

ie. output:

```
{ data: undefined, data2: 'bar' }
bar
```

*However*, this behaviour only seems to occur when I'm calling that `main()` function from the index file. If I do the same in `main.ts`

```
import {main} from "./index";

main();
```

I do not get this behaviour.

```
{ data: 'bar', data2: 'bar' }
bar
```

I imagine that the reason for this behaviour is something around node module resolution and cyclic dependencies - can someone explain exactly why this behaviour occurs?

Repo for this here: https://github.com/dwjohnston/import-from-parent-issue

Note that I've created this repro using TypeScript - I imagine that this isn't the cause of the issue - but it's the best way for me to reproduce the issue that I'm actually facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this happens because of circular dependencies.

So what happens in the first case:

1. Processing of `index.ts` is started
2. `index.ts` imports `foo/fooFile.ts`
3. Processing of `foo/fooFile.ts` is started
4. `foo/fooFile.ts` imports `index.ts`
5. `index.ts` is already being processed, in nodejs instead of `export blabla` you would use `exports` object and assign properties to it, then this object would be returned from `require` function when you `require` this file somewhere. If there is a circular dependency, the "unfinished" `exports` object is returned, so it gets properties that were already assigned to it, but nodejs doesn't try to continue executing file that `exports` this object to get the missing properties because of the circular dependency. So the "unfinished" `exports` object in this case is just an empty object because we didn't export anything. That means if you did `import * as obj from '..'` in `foo/fooFile.ts`, this `obj` would just be an empty object. Since you import `{ fooFile }`, `fooFile` becomes undefined

The rest of the process should be clear, by the time `main` function fires, `index.ts` has already exported some variables, including `file` variable, so the `main` function is able to use it.

Now the second case. I suppose that to see the issue I'm supposed to delete `main()` line in `index.ts`, because if I don't - I don't observe what you are talking about, it still shows `{ data: undefined, data2: 'bar' }`.

So I deleted this `main()` line in `index.ts`. It seems like everything should be the same, because anyway you import the same `index.ts` file, and it would in fact be so if it wasn't for a little issue:

> Note that I've created this repro using TypeScript - I imagine that this isn't the cause of the issue

It actually kind of is. If you compile this project and open `index.ts` file in both cases, you'll see this. First case:

```
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __exportStar = (this && this.__exportStar) || function(m, exports) {
    for (var p in m) if (p !== "default" && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(exports, p)) __createBinding(exports, m, p);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var fooFile_1 = require("./foo/fooFile");
__exportStar(require("./bar"), exports);
__exportStar(require("./foo/fooFile"), exports);
fooFile_1.main();
```

Second case, when I commented out `main()`:

```
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __exportStar = (this && this.__exportStar) || function(m, exports) {
    for (var p in m) if (p !== "default" && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(exports, p)) __createBinding(exports, m, p);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__exportStar(require("./bar"), exports);
__exportStar(require("./foo/fooFile"), exports);
// main()
```

Notice the difference? If you delete `main()`, then the first import in `index.ts`, that is `import { main } from './foo/fooFile'` becomes useless. Usually typescript wouldn't delete it, because even if import is useless, it may do some side effects, but here you anyway import something from `fooFile` later: `export * from './foo/fooFile'`. Well, not importing but reexporting, but in the context of nodejs that doesn't make any difference.

So now eveything starts to make sense:

1. Processing `main.ts` is started, it imports `index.ts`
2. Processing `index.ts` is started
3. `index.ts` imports `./bar`, gets the `fileName` and exports it. Now this "unfinished" `exports` object is not empty, it contains `{ fileName: 'bar' }`
4. `index.ts` imports `./foo/fooFile`
5. `./foo/fooFile` imports `index.ts`, but it already exported `fileName` so it can be used

The rest should be clear

You can assure yourself that this is what actually happens but changing the order of imports. Either manually add a line `require('./foo/fooFile')` to the compiled `index.js` file in the beginning, this way you will preserve the order of imports like in the first case and nothing will change. Or swap `./bar` and `./foo/fooFile` imports in `index.ts`, that will be the same.

This is partly caused by typescript, because if you just ran these files with nodejs, it wouldn't delete this unused import at the top and nothing would change again